# Colloquial term for a scam business

Tags: phrase-requests, slang, colloquialisms

There are many disreputable businesses that operate on the idea that you pay them for the privilege of trying to sell their product(s). Is there a common term for this kind of scam; one that could be used without an accompanying explanation?

For example:

> Yesterday, John was contacted by a door-to-door sales company. They wanted him to buy sets of knives, then cold call family/friends/strangers. I think this company might be a(n) _____.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a word or phrase that is specific to this kind of business model.

Comment: Mixed nouns and adjectives: mock, plaster, counterfeit, bogus, fictitious, phony, facade, bunco, charlatan, flimflam, hoax, swindle, hustle, false front.

Comment: @HotLicks: Those are some good terms; however, I've edited the question to clarify that I'm looking for a phrase that would be used to explicitly allude to that type of business.

Comment: You're talking about a *pyramid scheme*, or its slightly less disreputable cousin, *multi-level marketing* (MLM). More generically, a sham business may be called a *fly-by-night.*.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the specific business model you describe, you might be searching for the term ***MLM***. (Stands for **Multi-Level Marketing**).

So the entire sentence would read:

> Yesterday, John was contacted by a door-to-door sales company. They wanted him to buy sets of knives, then cold call family/friends/strangers. I think this company might be an **MLM**.

*Aside: To set the record straight, not every MLM is a scam. It is just a different business model some companies choose to use as their sales strategy. Many people do (incorrectly, IMO) perceive all MLM companies to be scams, however.*

Answer (score 0):

I think this company might be a sham.

noun: sham; plural noun: shams

```
1.
a thing that is not what it is purported to be.
"the proposed legislation is a farce and a sham"
```